# How to fix file upload error when using sendKeys(fileAbsolutePath) to <input type="file"> in Chrome 73?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, input-type-file

I have a Selenium WebDriver/JUnit test which tests file upload in Windows 10 via an `<input type="file">` element.

```java
File file = new File(filePath);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

HTML of `Browse` button:

```html
<label _ngcontent-cxx="" class="modal-button" for="file"> Browse 
    <input _ngcontent-cxx="" accept=".docx, .png, .pdf, .xlsx, .doc, .jpg" class="display-none" id="file" name="file" type="file">
</label>
```

The test worked well until Chrome 72, but after updating to Chrome 73 and chromedriver 73.0.3683.68 recently, file upload is not working. An error `Upload failed` is displayed in the UI and the upload request (POST) returns a status code 400. This happens only when running the automated test. Manual upload works fine.

A quick google search turned up [Chromium issue 792336](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792336) which is linked in [GitHub issue 3730 - File upload on input, stop working in Chrome 73](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3730).

```
File Inputs: Don't generate change events when 'files' is set

The <input type=file> element generates "change" events when the user
interacts with the control to select files, exposed as the 'files'
property (a FileList). This property can be assigned to by script, and
should not generate a "change" event in such a case. It was
erroneously doing so, so fix it.
```

I am not really sure I understand, but does this mean that automated file upload will no longer work in Chrome going forward? Or is there a way to make the file upload via an `<input type="file">` work in Chrome 73?

**NOTE**: I also tried using the `Robot` class to upload the file using the native Windows upload window, but file upload failed with the same error.

**StackTrace** (of the validation step after the upload step):

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //table[@id='table1']//*[contains(text(), 'license.pdf')] (tried for 8 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
        at pageObjects.BasePage.waitForElementToAppear(BasePage.java:116)
        at pageObjects.BasePage.uploadFile(BasePage.java:771)
        at stepDefinitions.testStepDefs.enterNameAndUploadLicenseDocument(testStepDefs.java:306)
        at ?.I enter the name and upload a license document(file:target/parallel/features/test_scenario001_run001_IT.feature:22)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@id='table1']//*[contains(text(), 'license.pdf
')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'host1', ip: '10.21.171.143', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e3..., userDataDir: C:\Users\user1\AppData\L...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:XXXXX}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpected
AlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.103, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 7de258a01764adc064e8c966xx77017g
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//table[@id='table1']//*[contains(text(), 'license.pdf')]}
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
        at pageObjects.BasePage.waitForElementToAppear(BasePage.java:116)
        at pageObjects.BasePage.uploadFile(BasePage.java:771)
        at stepDefinitions.testStepDefs.enterNameAndUploadLicenseDocument(testStepDefs.java:306)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
        at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:57)
        at cucumber.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
        at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)
        at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)
        at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:43)
        at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:46)
        at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:49)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:146)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:123)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:65)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:147)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

Comment: Update the question with the HTML and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB, HTML and stack trace updated.

Answer (score 0):

**Chrome 74** was released today and this is no longer an issue. Upload using sendKeys() via an `<input type="file">` element is working again with `Chrome 74/ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6`.